# Proving identity,division ring

Tags: ring-theory

In a ring$R$, suppose for all $x$$\in$$R$ there exists a unique $y$$\in$$R$ such that $x$$=$$x$$y$$x$.Then prove that i)$R$ has no zero divisors.
ii)If $x$$\neq$$0$ and $x$$=$ $x$$y$$x$ then $y$$=$$y$$x$$y$ for all $x$$,$$y$$\in$$R$.
iii)$R$ has an identity.
iv)$R$ is a division ring.please help me I am stucked .Pls help .

Comment: You have been warned numerous times to improve the quality of your questions and to seek answers before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The condition can only hold if $x\neq 0$ (otherwise $R$ is the trivial ring).

Moreover if $xa =0$, $x\neq 0$  then for the given $y$, one has $x(y+a)x =(xy)x = x$, so that by unicity, $y+a=y, a=0$: $x$ is not a zero divisor.

Furthermore let $x\neq 0$, $y$ be given by the condition. Then $yxy = yxyxy$ and so since there are no zero divisors, one can simplify on both sides by $yx$ to get $y = yxy$.

Let $x\neq 0$ and $y$ be given by the condition. Put $1 = yx$. Then for all $z$, $z1y = zy$ because $yxy = y$, and so simplifying by $y$, we get $z1 = z$. Similarly, $x1z = xz$ and so $1z = z$ : $R$ has an identity.

Now from this identity one gets $x = xyx \implies yx =1$. Simlarly, $xy =1$ (for $x\neq 0$ and $y$ given by the condition) : $R$ is a division ring.